# How to undo --no-verify-ssl in aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Basically, I was looking for answers for SSL Validation error that I am getting, while connecting airflow to AWS S3 bucket. With this being the easiest solution, I typed into the cmd prompt: `aws s3 ls --no-verify-ssl`

After this I read that disabling ssl is not a good thing to do, but I can't find a way to undo this. I am looking for something like: aws s3 ls --yes-verify-ssl, but that does not exist. So, please help me, if possible.

Comment: You don't have to reset anything as `--no-verify-ssl` supplied with the command does not set it globally. Just don't provide it next time you run `aws s3 ls` and you are good.

Comment: Thanks @Asdfg, Can you please let me know a command that can actually set --no-verify-ssl, globally, via aws cli? (This is with respect to a ssl validation error, for which i need an instant solution, as of now)

Comment: I do not believe there exists any config file setting for `no-verify-ssl`. You just have to pass that argument every time you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the command you provided it should have only applied an override to the default ssl-verification behavior while returning the list you were requesting by typing the 'ls'. Your config for s3 should be the same as before. If it had actually changed any settings, you could just run the command again with `--no-verify-ssl false` on order to revert the change.

[ls commands documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)